# Cypher query to find the node with the latest date

Tags: neo4j, cypher

An address node is connected to risk reports. Reports are ordered on a periodic basis, every year. I want to set a property for the latest report, for a given year. I was doing this while populating the data from SQL to Neo4j. Would like to know, if the same is possible through Cypher.

```
    MATCH path = (a)-[:`Assessment`]->(b) 
    return a.addressLine1 , b.reportYear, b.reportMonth
```

The nodes and respective properties are as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you want to set the property on the report or on the address.

something like this?

```
MATCH path = (a)-[:`Assessment`]->(b)
WITH a, b.reportYear as year, max(b.reportMonth) as month
MATCH path = (a)-[:`Assessment`]->(b)
WHERE b.reportYear=year AND b.reportMonth = month
SET b.lastOf=year
RETURN b
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly my requirement.